# Get value from Html.textbox in same markup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox, how can I get the value from it by writing code and declaring a variable in markup?

In the textbox the users is suppose to put in a value that I need as a counter in a loop. So all the code is in the same view

```
//Having a form here with some textboxes
@Html.TextBox("TextBox")

//Get value from "TextBox" here
@{var value = TextBoxValue}

//Using the value for my loop
@for (var i = 0; i < value; i++)
{
     //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Is it binded to the model? If not, the textbox is empty

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? May be there is a better way

Comment: @Andrei even if it is binded to model..you can get value first time what about if value changed by user

Comment: @Nilesh, if the value is changed by the user, there is no view. Valus is changed on the client side, and then sent to the server. View means we are rendering response, meaning there is either a model, or at very least a request info

Comment: No, there is no model for this value (I'm using it to count a loop)

Comment: @krillezzz Can you please describe a little bit more?

Comment: Why don't you use a model? You can loop trough a model in your view. You could try to use: string[] values = Request.Form.GetValues("TextBox"); Not tested, i have no idea if this works.

Comment: @RahulRJ have edited the question now

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use normal Javascript/ Jquery as::

```
<form>
    @Html.TextBox("TextBox1")
    @Html.TextBox("TextBox2")
    @Html.TextBox("TextBox3")

    @Html.TextBox("TextBox4")
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var textboxes = $("form input[type='text']")

        for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
            alert(textboxes[i].val());
        }
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible without js/jquery? don't wanna make my loop inside script tags

Comment: I have now made a model and TextBoxFor, but when I get the value (DisplayFor) I can't convert it into integer

Comment: @{var counter = Convert.ToInt32(Html.DisplayFor(m => m.periodCounter));}